# Generalised Eigenfunctions

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, taylor-expansion, hessian-matrix, eigenfunctions, generalized-eigenvector

Given $\mathbf{J}$, the Jacobian matrix of a function $\mathbf{F}:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, the system
$$
\mathbf{J}\mathbf{v}=\lambda \mathbf{v}
$$
has solutions corresponding to eigen-pairs $(\mathbf{v},\lambda)$, where $\mathbf{v}$ is an eigenvector of $\mathbf{J}$ and $\lambda$ its corresponding eigenvalue.

Is there a generalisation of the definition of eigenvector and eigenvalue involving the Hessian $\mathbf{H}$ of a function $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$? That is, is there a name for $(\mathbf{v},\lambda)$ satisfying
$$
\mathbf{H}\mathbf{v}=\lambda \mathbf{v}
$$
Alternatively (and perhaps more relevant), when $n=2$ (for simplicity) and considering the [vector-valued Taylor expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4469687/third-order-taylor-expansion-of-multivariate-vector-functions), is there any known eigen-based generalisation of $(\mathbf{v},\lambda)$ satisfying
$$
\frac12
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{v}^T \mathbf{H}_1(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{v}\\
\mathbf{v}^T \mathbf{H}_2(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{v}
\end{pmatrix}=
\lambda \mathbf{v}
$$
where, in this case, $\mathbf{F}=(F_1,F_2)$ and $\mathbf{H}_{1,2}$ are the Hessian matrices of $F_{1,2}$, respectively.

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe the eigenvalues of the Hessian are the [curvatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) of the local expansion.

Comment: @user619894 And can I say that the eigenvectors are the directions of the principle curvatures?

Comment: Yes, exactly. There is an n-ellipsoid that is described by the Hessian