# Third order taylor series for multivariable function?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

A lot of sources stop expanding the taylor approximation at the second order Hessian matrix for a multivariable function. I'd like to include the third order taylor expansion. Does anyone have the matrix equation for this and have any sources talking about it? Is there a name for the third order derivative matrix?

Comment: matrix equation? No. But, see my answers in [General form third degree multi variable Taylor polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4240056/568204) and more generally, [Taylor Series coordinate free form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4177847/568204).

Comment: https://sites.math.washington.edu/~folland/Math425/taylor2.pdf