# Taylor expansion of a sum of vectors

Tags: calculus, vectors, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative, hessian-matrix

I came across this problem in class where I had calculate the Taylor expansion of $f(\theta + \theta')$ where $f \in C^3(\mathbb{R}^3)$ using the hessian matrix $H_f$.

I was told that the solution was
$$
f(\theta) + Df(\theta)^\top\theta' + \frac{1}{2}{\theta'}^\top H_f \theta' + o\left({\theta'}^3\right)
$$
where o(-) denotes the little notation.

I can't figure out how to get to this result. I've tried rewriting the Taylor formula but I haven't been able to rearrange anything so that it matches the given solution. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I'm using this definition:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ a $k$-time continuously differentiable function at the point $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then there exists $h_\alpha : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ so that

\begin{align}
& f(\boldsymbol{x}) = \sum_{|\alpha|\leq k} \frac{D^\alpha f(\boldsymbol{a})}{\alpha!} (\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{a})^\alpha  + \sum_{|\alpha|=k} h_\alpha(\boldsymbol{x})(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{a})^\alpha, \\
& \mbox{and}\quad \lim_{\boldsymbol{x}\to \boldsymbol{a}}h_\alpha(\boldsymbol{x})=0.
\end{align}

Comment: This is pretty much what the multivariable Taylor's theorem tells us, so I'm not sure what you're asking to be proven. (Unles you want a proof of Taylor's theorem itself, in which case you should just look that up in a decent multivariable textbook). Edit: I just remembered I actually wrote several answers on Taylor's theorem's statement and proof and a whole bunch of other stuff related to it; so you should [probably start there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4177847/568204) and go through all the similarly linked posts.

Comment: @peek-a-boo My textbook gives me the definition I just added as the multivariable Taylor's theorem. I'm not too comfortable with hessian matrices yet so I can't really tell how I link the two together...

Comment: In your summation, can you explicitly write out the $|\alpha|=1$ terms? THen, try the same with $|\alpha|=2$. If you want, assume you're working in $\Bbb{R}^2$ to simplify matters slightly. The pattern should become clearer.