# Is there a Taylor expansion of a matrix-valued function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, matrix-calculus

Let $M : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ be a differentiable function that takes a vector as an input and returns a matrix as the output (for instance the Jacobian of some two variables real function $f$). Is it possible to expand this function with a Taylor series in some way? I was thinking of something along the following lines.

\begin{equation} 
A(v) = A(v_0) + \langle DA(v_0),v-v_0 \rangle + R,
\end{equation}

where $DA$ is some kind of operator that acts on vectors and returns a matrix and $R$ is the remainder.

Comment: Yes, differentiation, Taylor's theorem and a whole bunch of standard differential calculus works in the general setting of Banach spaces (real/complex vector spaces equipped with a norm, such that they are complete). See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4177847/568204) and the various links there.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "vector as input and matrix as output". Are you using "vector" to refer to elements of ${\mathbb R}^2$ and "matrix" to refer to an element of ${\mathbb R}^4$? If so, why the vector-matrix change in wording? If you're simply asking if it makes sense for a function from ${\mathbb R}^2$ to ${\mathbb R}^4$ to have a Taylor series expansion, then the answer is yes -- this is simply the [multivariable Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor's_theorem_for_multivariate_functions) one encounters in a multivariable calculus course.

Comment: Incidentally, more accessible than the Wikipedia article I just cited is [What is a good way to teach Taylor expansion of multi-variable calculus?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/18729/745)

Comment: There is a nice unconventional approach to this here: http://eprints.ma.man.ac.uk/2291/1/paper.pdf