# Hessian matrix of a multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I wanted to know if there is something similar to Taylor expansion for functions of form

$$f:R^n \longrightarrow R^m $$

Wikipedia gives the Jacobian for the functions of the above form, but the hessian matrix has been only defined for scalar valued functions of form $f:R^n \longrightarrow R$

So, does hessian exists for the function of form  $f:R^n \longrightarrow R^m $ and can a Taylor expansion be written for them?

Comment: It is the same (simply, the matrix entries are in $\Bbb R^m$). You can prove it by reasoning componentwise.

Comment: See [Taylor Series coordinate free form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4177847/568204) for the proper analogue of Taylor’s theorem in higher dimensions.