# Error term of Taylor approximation

Tags: real-analysis, limits, taylor-expansion

Let be $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ a $k$-times differentiable function and $T_k(x)$ its Taylor polynomial of $k$-th order about point $a$.

If we are closer to $a$ then the approximation gets better:
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-T_k(x)}{(x-a)^k}=0.
$$

To show this limit one could simply apply $k$-times rule of L'Hopital.

However, I would like to know if there is another way (without rule of L'Hopital) to prove this limit?

Comment: If you assume that the $k$th derivative is continuous, then you can use the integral form of the remainder to prove this. Basically, any of the various remainder formulas can help you prove your result easily.

Comment: This follows easily by the mean-value theorem and induction on $k$ (recall that $k=1$ is true by definition of differentiability of $f$ at $a$; at the induction step, use the mean-value theorem). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3272515/568204) for the details listed out in the higher dimensional case (I leave it to you to see how everything is simplified in the one-dimensional case).