# Reference Needed - Taylor's Theorem with Fréchet Derivatives

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, differential-topology, frechet-derivative

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_in_Fr%C3%A9chet_spaces#Properties), Taylor's Theorem holds for Fréchet derivatives, but no reference is given. I started looking in various books and they all mention that it is possible to write down a version of Taylor's theorems for Fréchet derivatives but no one seems to actually write it down.

Do you know of any precise reference?

Comment: See also [Proving limit of f(x) - Tnf(x) (Taylor) is zero, in multivariable calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3272515/568204). The proof follows easily with induction and the mean-value inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classical reference is the book "Differential calculus" by Henri Cartan, around section 5.6.